# How to convert several fields in SAS to numeric?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am working on a project where I'm reading raw census data into SAS enterprise guide to be processed as a different merged output. The first few columns are character fields, serving as geographic identifiers.

The rest of the raw data contains numeric fields, all fields are like "HD01_VD01" and so on up through numbers like "HD01_VD78". However, occasionally with census data numbers get suppressed and some observations have "*****" in the raw data like in the picture below. Whenever that happens, SAS reads in the numeric field as a character.

[image]

What would be a good way to ensure that anytime an "HD01_VD(whatevernumber)" is always numeric and converts "*****" to a blank/missing value like "." thus keeping the field numeric?

I don't want to hard-code every instance of a field being read in as a character back to numeric because my code is working with many different census tables. Would a macro variable be the way to do this? An if statement in each census table's data step?

Comment: Take a look at this document. If you use just a regular `proc import` statement the log will print out the corresponding data step. Then all you have to do is replace `proc import` with the data step and modify the formats. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/038-30.pdf

Comment: How are you reading in this data?  What format is it before coming to SAS?

Comment: They are csv's generated by the US Census Bureau's American Factfinder. I don't want to change the raw downloaded data, I want to manipulate my own versions in SAS. The margin of error fields occasionally get suppressed (HD02_VDwhatever) and are instead populated with *****, which is getting them converted to a character field. I want to preemptively find those and make them blank (.) so the columns read in as numeric in my PROC IMPORT statement.

Comment: So, you want all columns to be read in as numeric, but you don't know haw many columns to expect and how they will be called?

Comment: It is possible to automate what J_Lard suggests: read in the data in a first attempt, get the column names with a proc content and then contruct the correct data step to read it in. To that end you need to study macro programming.

Comment: A quick and dirty approach might be just to use array processing on all the character variables: `array x{*} _CHARACTER_` and process them in a `do` loop, and drop any columns you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays  and looping them  would be the best option; as mention in the comment by david25272.

Another option is to change the format of the fields in  Enterprise Guide either in:

Import Task taht reads the files: change the field to numeric

or

Add a Query Builder Task: and create calculate field and use this advanced expression `input(HD02_V36,11.)`